# Why category ids filter doesn't work on product export?

Tags: product, category, filter, export, magento-2.0.4

In Magento v2.0.4 Admin Panel go to `System > Data Transfer > Export` then select `Entity Type: Products`.

At that point the filtering grid appears.

The first option is `Categories` corresponding to `category_ids` product attribute; the text field brings us to think we can filter on it, maybe specifying the comma-separated list of category IDs.

But it doesn't work.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `category_ids` belongs to a special list of attributes which can't be used for filtering during export.

Here is where the list is defined:

```
// from magento/module-catalog-import-export
class Simple extends \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Overridden attributes parameters.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_attributeOverrides = [
        'has_options' => ['source_model' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean'],
        'required_options' => ['source_model' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean'],
        'created_at' => ['backend_type' => 'datetime'],
        'updated_at' => ['backend_type' => 'datetime'],
    ];

    /**
     * Array of attributes codes which are disabled for export.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_disabledAttrs = [
        'old_id',
        'tier_price',
        'category_ids',
        'has_options',
        'is_returnable',
        'required_options',
        'quantity_and_stock_status'
    ];
}
```

We can't comment out the `category_ids` attribute from the above array because it will throw an exception during the query build process.

I think that those attributes shouldn't appear in the filter options in the Admin Panel at least until a proper filter type will be implemented for that kind of attributes.

Hope it sheds some light on why filtering by categories doesn't work during export.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved in Magento 2.2.2.

You can see, article to resolve this issue.

See this [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184054/magento-2-exclude-category-from-magento-product-export-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top)