# Magento 2: Exclude category from magento product export not working?

Tags: magento2, importexport

I and trying to export the product from specific categoty. I am using following method to filter category id.

[image]

I have included all categories except 9. So i am expecting export result includes product from category 9. Is this correct? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should just input `9` on `category_ids` if you want to exclude this category. BUT please note that it WON'T exclude its child categories. Tested on M2.1.2 EE.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in Magento 2.2.2.

You can use following code to resolve this issue.

Add code to this file

> vendor\magento\module-catalog-import-export\Model\Export\Product.php

```
protected function _prepareEntityCollection(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection)
{
    $exportFilter = !empty($this->_parameters[\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP]) ?
        $this->_parameters[\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP] : [];

    if (isset($exportFilter['category_ids'])
        && trim($exportFilter['category_ids'])
        && $collection instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
    ) {
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => explode(',', $exportFilter['category_ids'])]);
    }

    return parent::_prepareEntityCollection($collection);
}
```

This code is resolved issue for me.

**You want exclude category id with its child categories so use this code given below**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc} 
 * @since 100.2.0
 */
protected function _prepareEntityCollection(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection)
{
    $exportFilter = !empty($this->_parameters[\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP]) ?
        $this->_parameters[\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP] : [];

    if (isset($exportFilter['category_ids'])
        && trim($exportFilter['category_ids'])
        && $collection instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
    ) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $export_cat_sub_ids = $export_category_ids = explode(',', $exportFilter['category_ids']);
        if (is_array($export_category_ids)) {
            foreach ($export_category_ids as $catId) {
                $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
                $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
                foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                    $export_cat_sub_ids[] = $subcat->getId();
                }
            }
            $export_cat_sub_ids = array_unique($export_cat_sub_ids);
        }
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $export_cat_sub_ids]);
    }

    return parent::_prepareEntityCollection($collection);
}
```